# Having trouble scanning and printing uint64_t (long long unsigned int)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t *ptr = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t));
    scanf("%llu",&ptr);
    printf("%llu\n", *ptr);
    free(ptr);
}
```

The compiler says that

```
mod_5_working.c:9:14: error: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format [-Werror=format=]
     scanf("%llu",&ptr);
              ^
mod_5_working.c:9:11: error: too many arguments for format [-Werror=format-extra-args]
     scanf("%llu",&ptr);
```

I've tried using `%u` but it says that I should use `%llu`.

Comment: Um, I'm pretty sure you're not supposed to feed it the address of a pointer to `uint64_t`...

Comment: If you’re using fixed width types already you may wish to include inttypes.h and use the appropriate scanf and printf conversions. I.E SCNu64 and PRIu64 respectively.

Comment: What OS are you targetting?

Comment: You should be using [`#include <inttypes.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.8.1) (instead of, or as well as, `#include <stdint.h>`), and then the correct format specification: `"%" SCNu64`.  That's the reliable way to generate the format for a `uint64_t`.

Comment: Observation: using dynamically allocated memory to point to a `uint64_t` uses far more memory than simply using a `uint64_t`.  The pointer uses 8 bytes; the allocation probably allocates 16 bytes (of which 8 are usable).  And there's a risk of not remembering to free the allocated memory (minimal risk in this example, but …).

Answer (score 2):

- `scanf("%llu",&ptr);` is senseless, like the compiler tells you, you are taking the address of a pointer.
- `uint64_t` doesn't necessarily correspond to `unsigned long long`. Some 64 bit systems use `unsigned long` for 64 bit numbers.

The correct, portable specifiers to use when scanning/printing `uint64_t` is `SCNu64` and `PRIu64` from inttypes.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t *ptr = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t));
    scanf("%"SCNu64, ptr);
    printf("%"PRIu64"\n", *ptr);
    free(ptr);
}
```

Comment: No need to `#include <stdint.h>`, already included from `inttypes.h`

Comment: @Roi Yes I know but I didn't wish to confuse the OP about that detail, since `stdint.h` is a commonly-used header and `inttypes.h` is somewhat exotic.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` expects a pointer, not a pointer to a pointer. Simply pass the pointer to `scanf`, no need to `&` it. Also you should always check the return value of `malloc` for errors.

```c
uint64_t *ptr = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t));
if (!ptr)
    return -1; /* Maybe handle it better */

scanf("%" SCNu64, ptr);
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", *ptr);

free(ptr);
```

Edit: It's a better practice to use `SCNu64` and `PRIu64` (from [`<inttypes.h>`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.8.1)) to make it portable and accurate.

Comment: `uint64_t` is _not_ certainly `long unsigned int`.  On another machine it may be `unsigned long long`, or others.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, it is arch specific. Usually it's `long unsigned int` on 64-bit platforms but you're right I should've mentioned it.

Comment: And therefore `%lu` is incorrect.

Comment: @Lundin Hmmm, not _really_ incorrect, major compilers accept it but in the long run it might not be very portable, that's true. I will change it though.

Comment: Incorrect = writing non-portable code just for the heck of it.

Comment: @Lundin Non-portable is not necessarily incorrect code. It's correct for my machine, unless you want to write portable code that's totally fine to use it. In fact most people don't bother to do that. Let's close it though (:

Comment: In this case it's not like there's a big effort required to make the code portable and it costs nothing in performance either. If the portability argument was "this isn't portable to one's complement computers" or "this isn't portable to EBCDIC" then that's another story.

Comment: The language specification's terminology would be "not strictly conforming".  I don't know whether "most people" intentionally disregard strict conformance, but even if they did, I don't accept that as a good reason recommend or model that.  In practice, the prevailing opinion here on SO is that strict conformance is a desirable goal.  You'll not find many regulars applauding wanton disregard for it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the matching specifier.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h> /* Format conversions for exact-width types */

scanf("%" SCNu64, ptr);  // No &.
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", *ptr);
```

Comment: Some vandal has deleted my comments. This answer is still incorrect: `PRNu64` -> `PRIu64`.

Comment: @Lundin Answer amended.